# Accept attribute Safari greys out allowed documents

Tags: html, safari

Works fine in most browsers accept...

OS X 10.7.5 - Firefox 30.0 + Safari 6.1.5

Here is the HTML:

`<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/do/upload_my_files" accept=".pdf,.docx,.doc,.xls,.xlsx,.txt,.csv,.ppt,.pptx,.zip,.rar,.psd,.txt,.pps,image/*" multiple>`

It shows only images available to select, all other files are greyed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-accept) allows only media types (MIME types) in the content of an `accept` attribute. HTML5 [extends](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#file-upload-state-%28type=file%29) this with notations like `.pdf`. Browsers that do not support the latter see your attribute just as `accept="image/*">`. Thus, add the media types (when available) such as `application/pdf` to the list, primarily using the authoritative [media type list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) by IANA. If this does not help, you are probably out of luck and should perhaps remove the attribute, if the browsers that don’t cope with it are important enough.

Comment: Is there a shim or anything I can use to hack it? :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and found that while Safari will not accept the comma-separated extensions, you can actually use the previously mentioned [IANA list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application) to address most types, including MS Office files (which is what I needed):

**.doc/.docx:** application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

**.xls/.xlsx:** application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

**.ppt/.pptx:** application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

It is working for me in both Chrome and Safari (6+). The IANA list doesn't make it easy to find what you need, but there is a handy list at [freeformatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html) that tells you exactly what to use for each extension.